# IndexedDB initWindowless in latest Firefox 33

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, indexeddb

After updating Firefox to v.33 my app crashes on this line:

`Components.classes["@mozilla.org/dom/indexeddb/manager;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIndexedDatabaseManager).initWindowless(sandbox);`

with the following error:

> Components.classes['@mozilla.org/dom/indexeddb/manager;1'] is undefined

As it [turned out](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1019194), they get rid of the nsIIndexedDatabaseManager which I use to access IndexedDB from the extension (sandbox).

How can I access IndexedDB now to store user's data (a lot of data I must say)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`Components.utils.importGlobalProperties(["indexedDB"])`

Thanks to [@boris-zbarsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720912/boris-zbarsky) ;)